# How to create weak reference in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, weak-references

i have a situation like this:

```
NSMutableArray * A = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initwithObjects:@"one",nil];
NSMutableArray * B = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initwithObjects:@"two",nil];

[A addObject:B];
[B addObject:A];
```

now here is a retain cycle, How can i break this retain cycle? (using weak reference)....in above example.
Thanks

Comment: The easy answer is don't do this. Why do you need to put B in A and A in B?

Comment: http://ofcodeandmen.poltras.com/2009/08/26/nsmutablearray-with-weak-references/

Answer (score 12):

I would question the reason you need to do this in the first place - but if you do decide it's the best data architecture, I would use `NSValue`. To store a reference to an object (without retaining it) in a Foundation collection class, you can use `+[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]`:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithObjects:@"one", nil];
NSMutableArray *b = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithObjects:@"two", nil];

[a addObject:b];
[b addObject:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:a]];
```

Then to get your object later on from the `NSValue` instance, you would do this:

```
NSMutableArray *c = (NSMutableArray *) [[b objectAtIndex:index] nonretainedObjectValue];
```

---

#### Addendum

I've changed the answer from using `+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]` to `+[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]`, since under ARC, the compiler will complain (due to casting from an object type to `const void *`). While functionally the same, the typecasting and method name makes more sense (and the compiler will actually let you compile without resorting to hackery).

Comment: I'd suggest using NSValue to create weak reference. It's obviously easy to understand and use, maybe the official implementation of weak reference. Usage of CFArrayCreateMutable function is not bad, however, it brings some inconsistence of usage of NSMutableArray, especially in exposed interface.

Comment: I agree 100% - messing around with non-standard `CFArray`s seems like a recipe for memory related bugs down the track if/when you've forgotten that your `NSMutableArray` behaves differently to 99.9% of `NSMutableArray` instances. Debugging with the `NSValue` technique, however, won't be in any way confusing or ambiguous.

Answer (score 8):

The way I've solved this problem in the past is to use a subclass of NSProxy to break the cycle. I'll have an object that stores a weak reference to one of the arrays and passes all messages except memory management ones through to it.

```
     ┌──── NSArray A <────┐
     │                    │
     │                    │
     v        weak        │
ACWeakProxy ┈ ┈ ┈ ┈ ┈ > NSArray B
```

---

```
@interface ACWeakProxy : NSProxy {
    id _object;
}

@property(assign) id object;

- (id)initWithObject:(id)object;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation ACWeakProxy

@synthesize object = _object;

- (id)initWithObject:(id)object {
    // no init method in superclass
    _object = object;
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass {
    return [super isKindOfClass:aClass] || [_object isKindOfClass:aClass];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
    [invocation setTarget:_object];
    [invocation invoke];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    return [_object methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
}

@end
```

---

Then your code becomes

```
NSMutableArray * A = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithObjects:@"one", nil];
NSMutableArray * B = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithObjects:@"two", nil];

[A addObject:B];
ACWeakProxy * proxy = [[ACWeakProxy alloc] initWithObject:A];
[B addObject:proxy];
[proxy release];

// will print "two"
NSLog(@"%@", [[[B objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

It is, however, up to you to make sure your weak reference doesn't vanish while you are still using it.

Comment: This solution works well with ARC's weak references. If you declare your property (and ivar) as weak the value becomes nil when the reference is lost. `@property(weak) id object;`

Comment: Wow this was a great find, thanks. I was using AVFoundation to record movie and unfortunately it seems `VideoFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:url recordingDelegate:` does not keep a weak reference and after some video source and sink had a cycle, but this proxy finally fixed the problem and now the object gets deallocated (it is a C++ wrapper for OSX)

Answer (score 7):

You could:

- manually break the cycle by removing the objects
- use [`CFArrayCreateMutable()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001502-CH201-F10961) and set the retain and release callback to `NULL`:

  ```
  CFArrayCallBacks acb = { 0, NULL, NULL, CFCopyDescription, CFEqual };
  NSMutableArray *noRetain = (NSMutableArray *)CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &acb);
  ```

Even better though, take a step back and think about how you can achieve what you want differently. With a proper design this problem might not even occur.

Answer (score 0):

In iPhone, there is no concept of weak reference. In your cases, I believe that it will cause the problem of over releasing on either of them.

Usually, for 2 classes, I will do something like this:

Let one class own another by retaining and the other just use assign. Some sample code may clarify it

class A

```
@interface A {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) B *b;
@end
```

class B

```
@interface B {

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) A *a;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the iPhone environment without garbage collection, a weak reference is more or less defined as a reference where the object is not retained.  With that in mind (actually even without that in mind), you have no control over whether NSMutableArray creates a weak reference or not.  In the GC environment, you still have the cycle, but it doesn't matter because once both objects unreachable, they'll both go away.

The only thing you can do is to manually break the cycle.  You do that by removing one of the arrays from the other.

Comment: Can you explain - You state that when both objects are unreachable they both go. But it is my understanding that an object goes away only when the retain count is zero. Is this something specific to GC?

Comment: @xcoder: yes, it is specific to GC.  GC works by taking a set of root objects (globals + those on the stack + some others) and sees which others are reachable (i.e. have references) from those root objects.  Anything else is deallocated.